# Automatically calculating and adding Landedcost

Tags: acumatica

I need to add a LandedCost in PO Receipt screen (PO302000) based on a fix percentage (which I can include as a custom field in PO Preferences). It should be automatically added by the time PO Receipt is released. Which event should be the best approach to trigger and add LandedCost?

Is that when user uncheck OnHold checkbox? 
Or, User clicks on Release button? If yes then can I extend release action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that releases the POReceipts is static we cannot override it.
However, we can override the places where this static method is being called. It is called in two places: **1)** on the release Action of POReceiptEntry(graph) and **2)** on the constructor of the POReleaseReceipt(graph) that sets the process delegate.

1) On the POReceiptEntry, you can extend this graph to first do your Custom code and then call base release method.

```
public class POReceiptEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<POReceiptEntry>
  {
        public PXSetup<POSetup> posetup;

        #region Event Handlers
        public PXAction<POReceipt> release;
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.Release, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
        [PXProcessButton]
        public virtual void Release()
        {
            //retrieve value from Custom field added on PO Preferences screen
            //POSetup setup = posetup.Current;
            //POSetupExt setupExt = setup.GetExtension<POSetupExt>();

            LandedCostTran landedCost = Base.landedCostTrans.Insert();
            landedCost.LandedCostCodeID = "YOURLANDEDCOSTCODE";
            landedCost.InvoiceNbr = "YOURINVOICENUMBER";
            landedCost.CuryLCAmount = 2;  //Formula here using setupExt.UsrFieldPercentange
            Base.landedCostTrans.Update(landedCost);

            Base.release.Press();
        }
    #endregion
  }
```

2) On the POReleaseReceipt graph, since the process delegate is set on the constructor of this graph, you can extend this graph and override **Initialize()** method to set your custom process delegate.
Your custom process delegate will have your custom code and then call base method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects;

namespace PX.Objects.PO
{

  public class POReleaseReceipt_Extension:PXGraphExtension<POReleaseReceipt>
  {
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            //Gets Process Delegate
            var processDelegate = (PXProcessingBase<POReceipt>.ProcessListDelegate)Base.Orders.GetProcessDelegate();

            //Change the process delegate that was created by the framework by your custom one.
            Base.Orders.SetProcessDelegate(delegate (List<POReceipt> orders) { POReceiptsProc(orders, processDelegate); });

        }

        public static void POReceiptsProc(List<POReceipt> orders, PXProcessingBase<POReceipt>.ProcessListDelegate processDelegate)
        {
            //Execute your custom code here
            //create POReceiptEntry graph, Loop through the orders,  Access your Custom field, Add LandedCost
            PXTrace.WriteInformation("Start Process execution");

            POReceiptEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<POReceiptEntry>();

            ........

            //Call the base action
            if (processDelegate != null)
                processDelegate(orders);
        }
    }
}
```